# Duplicate attributes error after manually deleting a migration and adding it again with the same name in ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I had a single migration called Initial Create, after revamping models I have deleted both migration and the database manually. 
After I recreated migration with the same name, it is acting as if the same migration already exists.

I tried deleting and recreating migrations and databases in every way but still, this happens if I use that same name, it is working with different names, but I wanna get to the bottom of this.
The only place as far as I know where migration could be saved is `_MigrationsHistory` in DB but I deleted everything.

example: Type `'InitialCreate'` already defines a member called `'BuildTargetModel'` with the same parameter types

Answer (score 0):

You can't just delete the migration file. You must remove it using the EF command:

```
dotnet ef migrations remove
```

When adding migrations, a `MyContextSnapshot.cs` file is added/modified, and this keeps a history of not just what migrations have been applied but which have been added. You'll likely have to delete this file, along with all the migrations and empty your database before you can start fresh. Then, just remember to always use the above command when you need to remove a migration you no longer want to apply.